# Brownian bridge interpolation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, brownian-motion, finance

I got stuck on a question goes like this:

> Let $W$ be a standard Brownian motion path. Suppose there are three times $0\leqslant t_1<t_2<t_3$. Denote the values at these times by $W_1$,$W_2$,$W_3$.  Find the conditional distribution of $W_2$ conditional on $W_1=w_1$,$W_3=w_3$ known (give mean vector and covariance). Explain Why the conditional on both $W_1$ and $W_3$ lower than only conditional on $W_1$.

I don't understand what's the role of given W3=w3 here. I know that Brownian motion is independent increment, but how I can derive some information about W2 given future W3...I feel lost here and don't know how to come up with mean and covariance.

I kind of understand why the variance might be smaller , because W3 is kind of constraint that at time between t1 and t3 you cannot go too far, because you need to come back to W3=w3 at time t3

Comment: Let me make it clear. There is only 1 Brownian motion. W1 W2 W3 is the value at 3 different time for this single Brownian motion

Comment: sorry I miss the word "conditional variance". It's to say why the conditional variance is lower.

Comment: Duplicate? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412470/conditional-distribution-in-brownian-motion

Comment: o!yes indeed. Thank you very much for directing me there